# Difference between List.iter and List.map function in OCaml

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml

I came across this function : `List.map`. What I have understood is that `List.map` takes a function and a list as an argument and transforms each element in the list.

`List.iter` does something similar (maybe?), For reference see the example below.:

```
# let f elem =
Printf.printf "I'm looking at element %d now\n" elem in
List.iter f my_list;;
I'm looking at element 1 now
I'm looking at element 2 now
I'm looking at element 3 now
I'm looking at element 4 now
I'm looking at element 5 now
I'm looking at element 6 now
I'm looking at element 7 now
I'm looking at element 8 now
I'm looking at element 9 now
I'm looking at element 10 now
- : unit = ()
```

Can someone explain the difference between `List.map` and `List.iter`?

NOTE: I am new to OCaml and functional programming.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`List.map` returns a new list formed from the results of calling the supplied function. `List.iter` just returns `()`, which is a specifically uninteresting value. I.e., `List.iter` is for when you just want to call a function that doesn't return anything interesting. In your example, `Printf.printf` in fact doesn't return an interesting value (it returns `()`).

Try the following:

```
List.map (fun x -> x + 1) [3; 5; 7; 9]
```

Answer (score 11):

Jeffrey already answered this question fairly thoroughly, but I would like to elaborate on it.

`List.map` takes a list of one type and puts each of its values through a function one at a time, and populates another list with those results, so running `List.map (string_of_int) [1;2;3]` is equivalent to the following:

```
[string_of_int 1; string_of_int 2; string_of_int 3]
```

`List.iter`, on the other hand, should be used when you only want the side effects of a function (e.g. `let s = ref 0 in List.iter (fun x -> s := !s + x) [1;2;3]`, or the example you gave in your code).

In summary, use `List.map` when you'd like to see something done *to* each element in a list, use `List.iter` when you'd like to see something done *with* each element in a list.